# Get all tweets from a user using python-twitter

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to retrieve all the tweets from a user in python with this [lib](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter).

The method provided in python-twitter to do this is defined as :

```
def GetUserTimeline(self,
user_id=None,
screen_name=None,
since_id=None,
max_id=None,
count=None,
include_rts=None,
trim_user=None,
exclude_replies=None):
```

Though if the count is limited to 200.

Documentation:

> count:
>           Specifies the number of statuses to retrieve. May not be
>           greater than 200.  [Optional]

My question now is: **Is it possible to retrieve all the tweets from a user with this lib ? And is there an alternative solution ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Twitter API explicitly says that you cannot retrieve more then 200 tweets from a user **per request** so this is not a limitation of this particular library you're using but a limitation imposed by Twitter. But keep in mind that this is per request, if you will send multiple requests you can get **up to 3200 tweets in total**. But this still means that you can't get all tweets, only 3200.

[Here is official Twitter API statuses/user_timeline endpoint documentation.](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

Comment: I figured as much, though it is very limiting. I can't specify the pages. In other words I can't make a request for the first 200 then another request for the next 200 and so on.

Comment: While it is not exactly pagination, you can take the lowest (i.e. oldest) tweet id in the reply from your first request and set that as the `max_id` in your second request and so on.